# Angular grid that is IE8 compatible?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-8

I am writing a ASP.NET MVC application (.NET framework 4.5.1) with AngularJS 1.2 and can't seem to find an AngularJS grid that works well with IE8. Unfortunately our clients are stuck with this browser for awhile.

I have tried, Angular UI Grid: http://ui-grid.info/ and also: http://www.ag-grid.com/. No luck with these plugins.

Comment: Have you tried ng-grid?  Could you give us some feedback so we can help you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try kendo grid it has Angular support now and works well on IE 8+.

Demo: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular

Answer (score 0):

You should use ng-grid and use the id="ng-app"

```
<div id="ng-app" ng-app ng-controller="UserController"> 
<b>Names</b> 
<ul> 
<li ng-repeat="user in userList"> 
<a href="#" ng-click="selectUser(user)">
{{user.getFullName()}}</a> 
</li> 
</ul> <hr> 
<b>Selected User</b>
<br> First Name: <input type=text ng-model="currentUser.firstName">       <br> 
Last Name: <input type=text ng-model="currentUser.lastName">
<br> Full Name: {{currentUser.getFullName()}}
</div>
```

For reference [visit](http://henriquat.re/appendix/angularjs-and-ie8/necessary-changes-for-ie8-compatibility.html)

For an illustrated MVC application in c# visit  [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_app.asp)